# Mule:Iterating over ArrayList

Tags: mule

I am trying to save an ArrayList into a flowVar & then iterate over the flowVar in a foreach statement, the code is as follows:

payload[2] is an array which part of arrayList.

```
      <foreach collection="#[flowVars['ID']]" doc:name="For Each"> 

        ....


     </foreach>
```

However I get the following error when I try to run this code:

org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:

---

Message               : not a statement (org.mule.mvel2.ScriptRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: LinkedList

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it **easily**  as the following example by declaring a variable as `java.util.ArrayList` as follows :-

```
<set-variable variableName="ID" value="#[new java.util.ArrayList(Arrays.asList('abc','def',66))]" doc:name="Variable"/>

<foreach collection="#[flowVars.ID]" counterVariableName="i" doc:name="For Each">
 <logger message="Value:- #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</foreach>
```

**Note**: if you want to **get a specific index** of Arraylist particularly, you don't need foreach, you can do it:-

```
<logger message="value at index 2: #[flowVars.ID[2]]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

**Alternately** in an **expression component**:

```
<set-variable variableName="ID" value="#[new java.util.ArrayList(Arrays.asList('abc','def',66))]" doc:name="Variable"/>

 <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[
     for(int i=0;i<flowVars.ID.size();i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Value "+ flowVars.ID[i]);
      }

     ]]></expression-component>
```

Comment: Quick question Anirban, if I was dealing with an Array of arrays doing #[flowVars.ID[i][2]] should work correct? I have an array of arrays where I need to check if every second element in the array is present in a DB or not

Answer (score 0):

@insaneyogi, here is a flow example that iterates over an arrayList as flowVar:

```
<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="test-foreachFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/foreach" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[myArray = new java.util.ArrayList();
myArray.add("el1");
myArray.add("el2");
myArray.add("el3");

flowVars.myArray =  myArray;]]></expression-component>
        <foreach collection="#[flowVars.myArray]" doc:name="For Each">
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]"/>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
</mule>
```